# Outlook contact list has two people with the same name

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook

I have two people in my contact list with the same name, say John Doe. These are two separate people, and I keep accidentally emailing the wrong one.

How can I prevent myself from emailing the wrong one. It's a company wide contact list so I can't remove the wrong one.

Details:
Contact Name: John Doe
Good email: j_doe@company.com
Wrong email: john_doe@company.com

Comment: use the middle initial for one of them but no the other? The system doesnt much care about the "friendly name" given to the e-mail address does it? Couldnt you even have "John the Great ToolGuy" and "John the Scientist" , or whatever that would not offend them?

Comment: It gives the suggestion from the address book, and the address book is company wide (5k+ employees), I'm not sure I can edit it, or should edit it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you to create an outgoing Outlook rule with condition "sent to john_doe@company.com" and actions "defer delivery by 10 minutes" and "flag message for CHECK!".

Configured this way, all emails sent to john_doe@company.com will be deferred by 10 minutes and marked with flag, appearing in your todo list.

Answer (score 0):

Save and store one as a 'Personal' Contact.

Comment: it then won't show up in the TO unless you really search for it